# XML sitemap generation Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, error, sitemaps

I am trying to index my online store pages when I generate the sitemap for my online store the only pages that are indexed are cart, checkout, login, create account pages. I have already enabled the sitemap options from system configuration and made necessary changes that are required in order to generate the sitemap.

P.S. I want it to be automatically generated and what I have noticed is the links that are listed in the sitemap are of 1 column layout. Does that have anything to do with column layout as catalog.xml has seo sitemap set for one-column layout?

Update to my question: With some conclusion I have drawn from the LINKS DEPTH on the xml generated sitemap is that the pages indexed are of link depth one (and so I think that does not have anything to do with the column layout)and it is not generating sitemap for pages that have link depth more than one would like to add I am using a custom mega menu) instead of the default menu that and when I disable the mega menu the sitemap generates the way it is expected to.

Comment: Are you using the sitemap functionality under `Catalog > Sitemap` in the Backend of Magento?

Comment: yes I have set the auto generate sitemap option to yes & it does create the sitemap when i am using the default magento menu it indexes pages with more than 1 link depth but with mega menu extension it generates sitemap for pages with only 1 link depth i.e., account, wishlist, cart, checkout, register and login pages.

Comment: *"with mega menu extension it generates sitemap for pages with only 1 link depth"* - have you contacted the developer about this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module and you should contact them.